# How to find malware on my Linux server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, malware

I have running Ubuntu Server 16.04.
Today I received several messages from my hosting provider, that there were detected email/http spam coming from my machine.

**Question:**
How can I find that malware?
What are best practices to follow in this situation?

Right now I changed passwords and blocked some outgoing ports with iptables ( 25, 80, 443 ).

Comment: Have a look at the log files for your mail server (Exim, for example). They sometimes (depending on the configuration) log the source of a message. It may be a script somewhere. You can also run tools like `RKHunter` or `ChkRoot` to scan for rootkits on the server. I assume this is a web server, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tools used to detect malwares on linux servers:

[Linux malware detect](https://github.com/rfxn/linux-malware-detect):

> Linux Malware Detect (LMD) is a malware scanner for Linux released under the 
>   GNU GPLv2 license, that is designed around the threats faced in shared hosted 
>   environments. It uses threat data from network edge intrusion detection 
>   systems to extract malware that is actively being used in attacks and 
>   generates signatures for detection.

[Lynis](https://cisofy.com/download/lynis/)

> Lynis is a security auditing tool for UNIX derivatives like Linux, macOS, BSD, Solaris, AIX, and others. It performs an in-depth security scan.

[rkhunter](https://linux.die.net/man/8/rkhunter) & `chkrootkit`

> rkhunter is a shell script which carries out various checks on the local system to try and detect known rootkits and malware. It also performs checks to see if commands have been modified, if the system startup files have been modified, and various checks on the network interfaces, including checks for listening applications.

[ISPProtect](https://ispprotect.com/)

you can [install](https://ispprotect.com/documentation/) the trial version of the malware scanner for web servers.

> What are best practices to follow in this situation?

Do not open the links provided by emails on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really your provider saying this? Give them a call. Also it could be someone knows your passwords to email accounts sending spam. You can install ClamAV and a gui for it. Google ClamAV and gui for Linux